# I need to match a and b variables to a list of x,y coordinates in a text file with certain conditions

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, csv, coordinates

Using python 2.7.

I have a text file full of x,y coordinates.

I want to match the different coordinate combinations available in the text file and assign it a number and also make it print out "cool". For example the 3,1 coordinate should be 1. The 1,1 coordinate should be 2 and the 3,3 coordinate should be 3.

I am having problems with the csv module for reading in my file.

I tried simplifying my code like this and it works but when I try reading in my file no successful matches occur.

```
coordinates = 'all_6_ligand_coordinates.dat'
a = 3
b = 1
with open(coordinates,'r') as file_in:
    reader = csv.reader(file_in)
    your_list = list(reader)
    for x, y in your_list:
        if x == a and y == b:
           print("Cool")
           print("1")
        else: 
           print("sucks to be you")
```

I expect my code to iterate over the all_6_ligand_coordinates.dat and if (x,y) is (3,1) it prints out "cool".

I have attached the all_6_ligand_coordinates.dat file as a dropbox link https://www.dropbox.com/s/p124z50pgozajrh/all_6_ligand_coordinates.dat?dl=0 .

Thank you for your help!

edit: forgot to add print("1")

Comment: [`cvs.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) returns "Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings.". Try changing `a` and `b` to strings with `a = '3'`, `b = '1'` then run your script again, should work as expected.

Comment: OH GOD, thank you. I was stuck on this for so long and it is so simple. Could you post it as an answer so I can make it the right answer? This worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list(reader)` returns a list of strings, which won't match when comparing to your integers.

Just need to change the two lines:

```
 a = 3   
 b = 1
```

---

```
import csv

coordinates = 'all_6_ligand_coordinates.dat'
a = '3'
b = '1'
with open(coordinates,'r') as file_in:
    reader = csv.reader(file_in)
    your_list = list(reader)
    for x, y in your_list:
        if x == a and y == b:
           print("Cool")
           print("1")
        else: 
           print("sucks to be you")
```

prints out a *long* list of about `88811` lines, some
`Cool
1`
and others
`sucks to be you`